# What is the purpose of this C Macro?

Tags: c, macros

I was reading opengl es book and in the source code i found this Macro

```
///
//  Macros
//
#define ESUTIL_API
#define ESCALLBACK
```

later in the implementation file .c

```
void ESUTIL_API esInitContext ( ESContext *esContext )
{
   if ( esContext != NULL )
   {
     memset( esContext, 0, sizeof( ESContext) );
   }
}
```

from what I understand macros, they just replace what is defined by the macro.. although i don't understand what it is the point in this case.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that's in the code? At https://code.google.com/p/angleproject/source/browse/trunk/samples/gles2_book/Common/esUtil.h?r=63#32 it's different.

Comment: Hi Tichodroma I checked your link and is different, the one Im referring to is [link]http://code.google.com/p/opengles-book-samples/source/browse/trunk/iPhone/Common/esUtil.c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This kind of macro is used to change the calling convention that is used by the compiler:

```
#define ESUTIL_API  // nothing, use the standard calling convention
```

or

```
#define ESUTIL_API __fastcall // use the fastcall calling convention
```

The call type calling convention has usually to be put in a function definition between the return type  and the function identifier name.

Comment: Ok, so if we leaving it empty it will be stdcall? Great I understand now, Thank you ouah

Comment: You have to read the documentation of your compiler, but usually default is cdecl.

Answer (score 0):

In this case is just a placeholder, in case one would ever need to add any decorations to the function declaration, more specifically, stuff like `__declspec(dllexport)`, calling conventions or inlining requirements.

Answer (score 0):

In this case ESUTIL_API macro can be replaced by the calling convention specification.

Answer (score 0):

There may be some other place (or condition) where that macro is defined differently - for example a -D option to a compiler, or another block of code that is triggered by some other `#define`s. In that case you *have* to define at least an empty macro so that you can safely use it in a declaration like that and if the macro happens to be re-defined to a non-empty value - it will be used as such.